Does scriptures mention Vedas as beings (in the image)?
There was a four images that shows the Vedas as beings:-

However, Do scriptures mention them as beings?

https://vanisource.org/wiki/SB_5.1.7?hl=personified%20Vedas SB 5.1.7 mentions Brahma descending from Satyaloka with personified Vedas, but I'll have to look further for descriptions matching yours.

Another: ŚB 10.87.14 has the 'śruti(s)' personified, speaking, and Srila Prabhupada interprets that to refer to the Vedas.

The Vedamūrtis are mentioned in Vratakhaṇḍa of Hemādri's Caturvargacintāmaṇi  (adhyāya 1, p. 104-5), on the basis of some Viśvakarmaśāstra —

ṛgvedaḥ śvetavarṇaḥ syāt dvibhujo rāsabhānanaḥ /  akṣamālādharaḥ
saumyaḥ prītaścādhyayanodyataḥ  //   ajāsyaḥ pītavarṇaḥ syāt
yajurvedo'kṣasūtradhṛk /  vāme kuliśa pāṇistu bhūtido
maṅgalapradaḥ //    nīlotpaladalābhāsaḥ sāmavedo hayānanaḥ / 
akṣamālānvito dakṣe vāme kambudharaḥ smṛtaḥ //    atharvaṇābhidho
vedo dhavalo markaṭānanaḥ /  akṣasūtra ca khaṭvāṅga vibhrāṇo
yajanapriyaḥ // 

Ṛgveda is śvetavarṇa, with two arms, donkey-faced, bears akṣamālā, is saumya, priya, and ever-udyata in adhyayana. Yajurveda is pītavarṇa, goat-faced,  bears akṣamālā, kuliśa (vajra) in left hand, is a bestower of aiśvarya & maṅgala. Sāmaveda has the varṇa of nīlotpala (blue water lily), horse-faced, bears akṣamālā on the right hand, and śaṅkha on the left hand. Atharvaveda is śvetavarṇa, markaṭa-faced, bears akṣamālā and khaṭvāṅga and is yajñapriya.

Image taken from the twitter post : https://x.com/vvaayu/status/801963677322805248
